# GTK, Keyboard focus in window containing ComboBox and DrawingArea

Tags: combobox, keyboard, focus

Keyboard keys left and right increments or decrements digit in window in this programm. When combobox is changed via mouse click, it work not. What can I do for correct function? I think, mouse click changes focus and I do not know, how it return. This is programm code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget *win, *fix, *com;
int Nr;

static gboolean Grafic(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer user_data) { int tx;
    tx=gtk_combo_box_get_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(com));
    if(tx) cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0); else cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 1, 1);
    cairo_rectangle(cr, 10, 34, 230, 230); cairo_fill(cr);
    if(tx) cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 1, 1); else cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
    cairo_select_font_face(cr, "Sans", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD); cairo_set_font_size(cr, 160);
    cairo_move_to(cr, 70, 200); tx=Nr+48; cairo_show_text(cr, (char*)&tx);
    return FALSE; }

gboolean Key(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
    if(((GdkEvent *)data)->type!=GDK_KEY_PRESS) return FALSE;
    switch(((GdkEvent *)data)->key.keyval) {
    case GDK_KEY_Left:  Nr--; break;
    case GDK_KEY_Right: Nr++; break;
    default: return FALSE; }
    Nr&=7; gtk_widget_queue_draw(win); return TRUE; }
gboolean Change(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
    gtk_widget_queue_draw(win); return FALSE; }

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv); win=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(win), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(win, 250, 280);
    gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(win), FALSE);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(win), "Positiv / Negativ");
    fix=gtk_fixed_new(); gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(win), fix);

    com=gtk_combo_box_text_new();
    gtk_combo_box_text_append(GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(com), NULL, "Positiv");
    gtk_combo_box_text_append(GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(com), NULL, "Negativ");
    gtk_combo_box_set_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(com), 0);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(com, 120, 30); gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fix), com, 60, 2);
    g_signal_connect(GTK_COMBO_BOX(com), "changed", G_CALLBACK(Change), NULL);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(fix), "draw", G_CALLBACK(Grafic), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(win), "key-press-event", G_CALLBACK(Key), gtk_get_current_event());

    gtk_widget_show_all(win);
    gtk_main(); return 0; }
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific than "it work not"? Screenshots of the problem would be helpful. Thanks for posting code, though.

Comment: Keyboard keys left and right does absolutely nothing